# How do I provide a session token when using FlinkKinesisConsumer in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to use user A to assume role R1, and using R1 assume R2 in a different account. I have gone as far as creating an StsClient to get the accessKeyId, secretKeyId, and sessionToken that I need, but based on Flink's documentation there is no way for me to provide this property and that's causing me to get the following error:

`Caused by: org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.AmazonKinesisException: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

Here's my code:

```
public class TestKinesisConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // AWS Code
        StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_WEST_1)
                .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create("someProfile"))
                .build();
        AssumeRoleResponse assumeRoleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(
                AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                .roleArn("arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/R1")
                .roleSessionName("AssumeRole")
                .build()
        );
        stsClient = StsClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_WEST_1)
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsSessionCredentials.create(
                        assumeRoleResponse.credentials().accessKeyId(),
                        assumeRoleResponse.credentials().secretAccessKey(),
                        assumeRoleResponse.credentials().sessionToken()
                ))).build();
        assumeRoleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(
                AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                        .roleArn("arn:aws:iam::09876543210:role/R2")
                        .roleSessionName("CrossAccount")
                        .build()
        );
        
        // Flink Code
        Properties consumerConfig = new Properties();

        consumerConfig.setProperty(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, Region.US_WEST_1);
        consumerConfig.setProperty(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, assumeRoleResponse.credentials().accessKeyId());
        consumerConfig.setProperty(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, assumeRoleResponse.credentials().secretAccessKey());
        consumerConfig.setProperty(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME, "CrossAccount");
        consumerConfig.setProperty(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ROLE_ARN, "arn:aws:iam::09876543210:role/R2");

        consumerConfig.setProperty("flink.stream.initpos", "TRIM_HORIZON");

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        FlinkKinesisConsumer<String> kinesis = new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>(
                "TestFlinkConsumerStream", new SimpleStringSchema(), consumerConfig);

        env.addSource(kinesis).addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>());
        env.execute("TestFlinkConsumer");
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the program to output the contents of the Kinesis stream in the other account after successfully assuming the role R2.

Comment: did you get an answer?